# Is there a way to make myself sleep quickly without resorting to sleeping pills or any sleeping foods?

Tags: sleeping

It's hard for me to sleep quickly. Sometimes it took me 1-2 hours (not always) on my bed to make myself asleep. So is there any way to make me sleep in around 5-10 mins? I hate it when I can't get enough sleep for work. Thank you

**Edit:**

I'm looking some sort of physical technique that make/force you to sleep. Not a habit that must be done daily.

Comment: Can you clarify about eating? In your title you ask about eating, but don't mention it in the question.

Comment: well, what i mean taking some sleeping pills or eating any food ( bread, cereal etc).

Comment: I personally find it really hard to sleep when I'm hungry too.

Comment: so, do you know how to make me sleep faster?

Comment: Wait, do you mean you eat well during the day, but you don't want to use food to put yourself to sleep?

Comment: @axsvl77 yes :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to train myself to fall asleep faster?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/how-to-train-myself-to-fall-asleep-faster)

Comment: Read "The Book of Mormon"

Answer (score 5):

Proven aids to falling asleep faster:

Sleep alone; a bed partner will disturb with movements, snoring, talking, and may distract with other bedroom activities.

Avoid backlit or self-lit displays (computer, cell phone/tablet, TV, etc.) for an hour before bedtime.

Eliminate caffeine (coffee, tea, sodas) for at least the last six hours before bedtime; preferably, completely quit using caffeine.

Don't smoke immediately before bed (and especially don't smoke *in* bed; this is a serious hazard of dying in a fire if you should fall asleep with a lit cigarette in hand or mouth).

Make the bedroom as dark as is practical.

Use a noise generator or recording of surf, rain, or forest sounds (whatever you find restful) to cover outside sound (traffic, others in the house, etc.).

Go to bed at the same time every night -- weeknights and weekends -- and get up the same time every day, even if you're not fully rested (this resets your daily rhythm to the schedule you need for workdays; sleeping in on the weekend disrupts that rhythm).  Allow at least seven hours, preferably eight, for sleep -- from light out (if you read or do other things in bed) until your alarm time.

Note that experts say that if you take less than twenty minutes to fall asleep in a dark room without distractions, you are probably sleep deprived; don't put too much emphasis on trying to get to sleep in ten minutes.  On the other hand, if you're doing all these things and still can't get to sleep in under an hour, and still exhibit symptoms of sleep deprivation (tendency to fall asleep during the day without constant stimulus is high on the list), you should get your doctor to refer you to a sleep specialist; you may have a sleep disorder (insomnia, sleep apnea, or something less common).

None of this is really a "life hack", it's all just good practice *everyone* in our habitually sleep-deprived society should follow (though many/most of us can dispense with some of these if they aren't causing trouble).

Comment: For a noise generator, we use a box fan all year long.

Comment: Fans work well for this.  Window air conditioners, too.  But when it's cold, there are inexpensive machines that make the rushing sound without the chilling breeze -- or CDs (probably MP3 downloads now, mine is 30 years old) with ambient sound recordings.  Surf at quite moderate volume will cover even traffic on a busy street, as long as there isn't an accident.

Comment: When it's cold - or even throughout the year, an air purifier (basically a tower fan with a HEPA filter attached to it) also makes a good "sleep noise" machine.

Comment: 1. I sleep alone
2. When I am going to sleep I turn off every single light (total dark)
3. For caffeine, I'm not sure i can do that :)
4. Noise generator (I'm not really sure what is this, some sort of song to make me feel sleepy? I'll try it tonight)

well, it's a habit that need to do daily to work right. I don't think i can do that. because my work sometimes force me not to sleep. (you know programmer). So, I'm looking some sort of physical technique that make/force you to sleep. Something like , Do 200 sit up and you'll sleep almost instantly.

Comment: "_if you take less than twenty minutes to fall asleep in a dark room without distractions, you are probably sleep deprived_" That's interesting... Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Try this article:  http://www.compassconsultation.com/sleep-and-rest-life-sleeping-like-an-eight-year-old/  -- don't know what their source is, but this isn't where I read it originally.  That was several years ago, though, so may not still be on line.

Comment: @Vahn  if you're going to continue your bad habits, you're going to continue having trouble getting to sleep and continue to be sleep deprived.  OTOH, if you're very sleep deprived and not caffeinated *at bedtime*, you'll probably fall asleep pretty quickly (possibly even at stop lights in traffic, or while actively driving, which is one reason this is dangerous).  If nothing else, you MUST stop using caffeine at least 5-6 hours before bedtime.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon  Yeah. I some times get micro sleep a lot. That's why I search the way to make myself sleep almost instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'cognitive shuffle'. I recently read about it in [Oliver Burkeman's column](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2016/jul/15/shuffle-thoughts-sleep-oliver-burkeman):

Essentially, you just visualise random objects. This tricks your brain into thinking it's done for the day with nothing important going on. I have found it effective.

Answer (score 0):

Hot milk with honey works a treat. Or does that count as food?